# JSON deserialization works from test but not from servlet

Tags: java, json, jackson, nosuchmethoderror, fasterxml

I am using the following code to deserialize a JSON object:

```
System.out.println("Trying to deserialize the following string: " + jsonString);
DRRequest elements = JSONMapper.objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, DRRequest.class);
System.out.println("Done, the resulting object is: " + elements);
```

When I call the code from the test, it works properly and I get the following output:

```
Trying to deserialize the following string: { "start_time":"2015-10-19T13:00:00.000+02:00", "interval":900,"unit":"kW","target_values": [50.3253179, 45.15539599955082, 56.13061499595642, 68.14941400289536, 65.17419399321079, 63.140625, 47.14074699580669, 28.16027800738811, 61.14758299291134],"prosumers_primary":[  "Pr_1","Pr_4","Pr_7","Pr_1"],"prosumers_secondary":[  "Pr_2","Pr_3","Pr_8","Pr_11","Pr_16"]}
Done, the resulting object is: com.wattics.vimen.DSSdata.DRRequest@5ae50ce6
```

But when I try to use the code from the servlet, I get the following error:

```
Info:   Trying to deserialize the following string: { "start_time":"2015-10-19T13:00:00.000+02:00", "interval":900,"unit":"kW","target_values": [50.3253179, 45.15539599955082, 56.13061499595642, 68.14941400289536, 65.17419399321079, 63.140625, 47.14074699580669, 28.16027800738811, 61.14758299291134],"prosumers_primary":[  "Pr_1","Pr_4","Pr_7","Pr_1"],"prosumers_secondary":[  "Pr_2","Pr_3","Pr_8","Pr_11","Pr_16"]}
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[DSSRequest]: Servlet.service() for servlet DSSRequest threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.JodaDateDeserializerBase.findFormatOverrides(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.JodaDateDeserializerBase.createContextual(JodaDateDeserializerBase.java:35)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:653)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:408)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:881)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:436)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:242)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:143)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:439)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3666)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3558)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2578)
    at com.wattics.vimen.DSSdata.DSSRequestsJsonMapper.readValueFromJson(DSSRequestsJsonMapper.java:37)
    at com.wattics.vimen.DSSdata.DSSRequestsJsonMapper.deserialiseDRRequest(DSSRequestsJsonMapper.java:19)
    at com.wattics.vimsen.GDRMmanager.DRPostRequestManager.storeJsonDRRequest(DRPostRequestManager.java:60)
    at com.wattics.vimsen.GDRMmanager.DRPostRequestManager.storeJsonDRRequestReturnJsonAck(DRPostRequestManager.java:35)
    at com.wattics.vimsen.GDRMmanager.DSSManager.storeDRRequestReturnAck(DSSManager.java:33)
    at com.wattics.vimsen.webapi.DSSRequest.doPost(DSSRequest.java:110)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can anyone help me understand what is causing the Exception, how to fix it?

The code of the associated class looks like this:

```
package com.wattics.vimen.DSSdata;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DRRequest {

  public DateTime start_time;
  public String start_time_text;
  public int interval;
  public String unit;
  public Double[] target_values;
  public String[] prosumers_primary;
  public String[] prosumers_secondary;
  public String type;

}
```

In file `pom.xml` there are the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>                                                              
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>                                    
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>                                
        <version>2.5</version>                                              
        <scope>provided</scope>                                             
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>                   
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>                      
        <version>2.8.1</version>                                            
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <!-- Note: core-annotations version x.y.0 is generally compatible with
        (identical to) version x.y.1, x.y.2, etc. -->                       
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>                       
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>                        
        <version>2.8.1</version>                                            
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>                       
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>                               
        <version>2.8.1</version>                                            
    </dependency>                                                           

    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>                                   
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>                            
        <version>1.1.3</version>                                            
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                                       
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                                     
        <version>6.8.8</version>                                            
        <scope>test</scope>                                                 
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>com.wattics</groupId>                                      
        <artifactId>vimsenGDRMdb</artifactId>                               
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>                                   
    </dependency>                                                           
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I think it is missing joda dependency in your class path.

Comment: It seems your `JSONMapper.objectMapper` has a different configuration when run from the test than from the production code

Comment: @AdamSiemion: where would that configuration be? I have the following config files in the project, and none of seem to have anything related... `src/main/resources/localhostTestConfig.cfg.xml
src/main/resources/logback.xml
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
src/main/java/com/hibernate.cfg.xml` Note that I am trying to run a project that someone else wrote, so I don't have good knowledge of the setup

Comment: @SachinGupta: But how to add it to Glassfish's classpath? I donwloaded `jackson-datatype-joda-2.8.1.jar` and put it in `~GlassFish_Server/glassfish/modules/`, but the error is still the same. But I think that you are right about the dependency, because when I comment the DateTime field from the class, then it doesn't cause any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was something wrong with Glassfish's configuration. I deployed on tomcat8 and works properly.